Let $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots +a_{2m}x^{2m}$ be a polynomial with $a_0=a_{2m}=1$.
If each root of $f(x)$ is complex and has multiplicity $m$, show that $a_m$ must belong to a finite interval.
Clearly $f(x)$ has two distinct roots each of multiplicity $m$. So $f(x)$ is of the form $(x-\alpha)^m(x-\beta)^m$. Also $a_0=1$ implies $\alpha^m\beta^m=1$. We can get $$a_m=\sum_{r=0}^{m} \binom{m}{r} \binom{m}{m-r}\alpha^r\beta^{m-r}$$
where $\binom{m}{r}$ denotes the number of possible combinations of $r$ elements from $m$ elements. Now how to show that $a_m$ must belong to a finite interval.

Do we assume $a_k\in\Bbb R$?

You're close with what you have.
Observe that $ f(x) = (x^2 + ax + 1) ^m$, where $ a \in (-2, 2)$.
Use the multinomial theorem to show that $ a_m = g(a, m), $ where $g$ is a polynomial in $a$.
Hence $g$ takes $ (-2, 2)$ into a finite interval.
Note: We're not asked to determine the end points, though I believe that they are defined by infimum = $ \min (g(-2, m) , g(0, m) )$ and supremum = $g(2, m)$.
